# Why am I getting different results filtering with foreach vs LINQ .Where()?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, sitecore

I seem to be getting different results when filtering.

**I expect the same result from these two pieces of code** :

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item firstGuess = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(mediaPath);
var matches = new List<Item>();

//Method A
foreach (var child in firstGuess.Parent.Children.InnerChildren)
{
    if (child.DisplayName == firstGuess.DisplayName)
    {
            matches.Add(child);
    }
} 
//Matches.count  = 2

//Method B
var matches2 = firstGuess.Parent.Children.InnerChildren.Where(i => i.DisplayName == firstGuess.DisplayName);
//matches2.any = false
```

I am trying to find items which have the same name as my `firstGuess`.

Method A works as expected, but B seems to give me a odd result in that `!matches2.any()` returns `false`, when I would expect `true`.

Tested with both `.Where` and `.Select`

**Why do are these *seemingly equivalent* methods give me *different results*?**

Comment: You should use `.Where` not `Select`. Method B will have True/False as property value not a model of `InnerChildren` whatever it is which is not "odd" as this is exactly what you're asking it to do.

Comment: I tested with both, and it dodn not work.

Comment: I just want to return a list which consist of a filtered list of innerchilds which fullfill the criteria set..

Comment: How do you determine that the LINQ query didn't return anything? Post something that can actually reproduce the problem

Comment: What happens if you put `.ToList()` at the end of the firstl ine

Comment: Then please explain what the 'odd' result it is generating. As your code stands in this question, it would produce the same output from both methods unless you're doing something else that's not detailed above.

Comment: Its possible that iterating over `firstGuess` for method A is playing out the `IEnumerable` so `matches2` doesn't have anything left to iterate over. Try running the `matches2` declaration (Method B) to see if you get your two results.

Comment: @DanSchnau that was about the only guess that I had, as well, but whatever's going on in one of those collections must be _funky_ for that to be the case.

Comment: @MrVoid `.Any()` will force evaluation

Comment: I'd bet Sitecore doesn't retrieve anything until you actually try to enumerate the data. This means that once `foreach` is finished, there's nothing else to query.

Comment: I think if we find out what the 'odd' result is we could fast and painlessly put an end to this misery rather than throwing blind guesses.

Comment: I bet @anita has more code after this and forgot that Linq queries are lazy loaded. Can you show us more code? Do you have any more code between this and the actual Any() Evaluation?

Comment: In short - this shouldn't happen. I think you need to show implementation of these classes for further analysis. What is `InnerChildren`? Show how these properties / methods are implemented. Try to debug it and see what is `InnerChildren` and show the contents. Is there `IQueryable` or `Expression`s taking place anywhere?

Comment: Try creating a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for this - I'm willing to bet that in the process of doing so, you'll discover a bug in _your_ code and not in Microsoft's. As it stands, there's nothing in your code that's going to produce different results between `matches` and `matches2`, and the snippet from you question is not runnable on its own.

Comment: @RicardoAlves I actually don't have more code than this...
I am currently trying to intercept the MediaRequst Pipeline, which is does, but seem to be having problems with this query. 

The fallback condition (n case of it is actually emtpy) seem to be triggered all the time, eventhough it is not the case / or shiould not..

Comment: @anita: But, you can write more code.  Create a class that mimics the structure of your first guess.  Stuff it with some sample data, then run the code you have (above) an see if you get the same response.  It might be that you have an "observer problem" - that's the problem you get in the case that by simply looking at something, the act of looking at it changes what you are looking at.  As a result, when you look at it a second time, it's not the same.  None of use can execute your `Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem` code.  If you give us something to play with, maybe we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without more info, but you could try this, i.e. ensure you are not suffering from mutation of firstGuess in the foreach loop. Get the result twice.

```
var firstGuess = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(mediaPath);
var firstGuess2 = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(mediaPath);
var matches = new List<Item>();

//Method A
foreach (var child in firstGuess.Parent.Children.InnerChildren)
{
    if (child.DisplayName == firstGuess.DisplayName)
    {
        matches.Add(child);
    }
} //Matches.count  = 2

//Method B
var matches2 = firstGuess2.Parent.Children.InnerChildren.Where(i => i.DisplayName == firstGuess.DisplayName).ToList();
```

And also **ToList() the where to ensure the IQueryable<> is definitely executed**.

Generally - if you find something unexpected in code like this - replace `var`  with the explicit types - this may well make the oddity apparent.

Comment: So adding `.toList()` at the end seem to filter it correct.. Now is the question why that work, and without the the `.toList()` it does not?

Comment: @anita `.ToList()` will force enumeration, otherwise the LINQ methods are lazy by default

Comment: @anita If the "ToList" worked then the problem is what I told you in a comment: Linq Queries are Lazy loaded which means that, when you use "Where" it actually doesn't do anything. The result of the operation "Where" will only be visible when you iterate the IEnumerable. So, if you modify the "firstGuess2.Parent.Children.InnerChildren" before the iteration (or Any()) you will end up with an "unexpected result". The ToList() forces it to evaluate the Where immediately.